# Printing complete traversal of tree using DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm trying to print the traversal of a graph starting from the root node, down the graph, and back up to the root node. For example, if this is the graph:

```
          0             
         /
        1
       / \
      3   4
     / 
    2
```

I want to print: 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 0

I'm currently using DFS to print 0, 1, 3, 2, 4. How do I modify my algorithm to print the backtracking too?

DFS Code:

```
def dfs(graph, start, visited=None):
if visited is None:
    visited = set()
visited.add(start)
print(start)
for next in graph[start] - visited:
    dfs(graph, next, visited)
return visited
```

Comment: usually these kind of problem can be solved adding a statement after recursive call but before returning. (eventually splitting return value in a temp var)

Comment: _I'm currently using DFS to print 0, 1, 3, 2, 4_ post [mre] version of your code please

Comment: Added my dfs code

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the data structure for that like `parent: children[]` pairs. Then you can resolve the problem like:

```js
const ROOT = 0;
const tree = {
    /* parent: children[] */
    [ROOT]: [1],
    1: [3, 4],
    3: [2],
    4: [],
    2: []
};

const pathStack = [];

pathStack.peek = () => pathStack[pathStack.length - 1];
pathStack.push(ROOT);

const traverse = () => {
    const node = pathStack.peek();

    if (node == null) { // if path is over, stop
        return;
    }

    console.log(node); // print the node

    const children = tree[node];

    if (!children.length) { // if children doesn't exist, go to its parent
        pathStack.pop();
        traverse();

        return;
    }

    const child = tree[node].shift();

    pathStack.push(child); // go to its child
    traverse();
};

traverse();
```

I don't know what the language you use is. So I used JS.
I think you can get the core idea of the algorithm in the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the complete path, you just need to remember the parent from which you came from and after all the children are traversed, print the parent value.
A pseudo code is as below:

```
dfs(graph, node, parent, visited)
   if (visited[node]) return
   visited[node] = true
   print(node.value)
   for ( neighbor : graph.neighbors(node) )
      dfs(graph, neighbor, node, visited)
   if ( parent != null) print(parent.value)
```

And you could call this method as : `dfs(graph, start, null, visited)`